# How to download Landsat 8 images using Amazon S3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-colaboratory, landsat

I implemented python code from the [Automated Bulk Downloads of Landsat-8 Data Products in Python | Geology and Python](http://geologyandpython.com/get-landsat-8.html) tutorial.

It works pretty okay, but I want to retrieve data on the basis of date.I even changed some of code and tried but have not succeeded.

```
bulk_list = []

# Iterate through paths and rows
for path, row in zip(paths, rows):

print('Path:',path, 'Row:', row)

# Filter the Landsat Amazon S3 table for images matching path, row, cloudcover and processing state.
scenes = s3_scenes[(s3_scenes.path == path) & (s3_scenes.row == row) & 
                   (s3_scenes.cloudCover <= 15) & 
                   (s3_scenes.acquisitionDate='2019-04-22')
                   (~s3_scenes.productId.str.contains('_T2')) &
                   (~s3_scenes.productId.str.contains('_RT'))]
print(' Found {} images\n'.format(len(scenes)))

# If any scenes exists, select the one that have the minimum cloudCover.
if len(scenes):
    scene = scenes.sort_values('acquisitionDate').iloc[0]

# Add the selected scene to the bulk download list.
bulk_list.append(scene)
```

but it throws an error:

```
File "<ipython-input-37-ec27c752ae7e>", line 11
(s3_scenes.acquisitionDate='2019-04-22')
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I understand there is problem in date format but couldn't resolve.

Please also suggest me some good tutorials to of AWS on Landsat 8 images.

as I print bulk list
    bulk_list
`[productId            LC08_L1TP_152042_20190422_20190507_01_T1
    entityId           LC81520422019112LGN00
    acquisitionDate    2019-04-22 05:56:08.442691
    cloudCover         0
    processingLevel    L1TP
    path               152
    row                42
    min_lat            24.9171
    min_lon            66.742
    max_lat            27.0339
    max_lon            69.0604
    download_url       https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/landsat-pds...
    Name: 1520154, dtype: object]`

and even after I used `(s3_scenes.acquisitionDate='2019-04-22 05:56:08.442691')` result remains same

Comment: I already did this tutorial, I guess you should have use '==' instead of simple '=' in pandas DataFrame filtering, or even '>='. My problem is that with this method, it's painfully slow :S

Comment: is there a reason this list (https://landsat-pds.s3.amazonaws.com/scene_list.gz) does not come with `productId` column? I'm trying to perform the same filtering without that. Is there another scene_list.gz that comes with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the date format shoud be `YYYYMMDD`

for more info see [amazon](https://docs.opendata.aws/landsat-pds/readme.html)

or simply use `s3_scenes.productId.str.contains('20190422')`

and you forget `&` at the end of the statement